# A unicode newline character(\u000d) in Java

Tags: java, unicode

Let's see the following code snippet in Java.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // new Character(' \u000d System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

---

In the above code, although the only line in the `main()` method is commented out, it displays the output `Hello` on the console, even though it looks like that this commented line contains some syntax errors. If this line is uncommented, it will not work at all, causing a compile-time error.

Why does it output "Hello" here?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/few-tricky-programs-in-java/   :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Java parses character escape codes in source code, not just strings.
This allows you to use Unicode identifiers without a Unicode encoding.

Therefore, the `\u000d` in the comment is parsed as a newline, ending the comment and beginning an instance initializer.

Comment: \u000d is for CR (Carriage Return) and 
\u000a is for LF (Line Feed)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters