# Escaping % in ICS Preferences - Do I really have to write version specific string handling?

Tags: android, string, escaping, preferences

I have an app that crashes on ICS.  Worked fine up to then (though I'm not sure if I ever really got a honeycomb platform to test on, all of our test phones are either gingerbread or lower, and now I have a couple ICS phones to play with).

The following code (called from onResume and OnPreferenceChangeListener) from my preferences page has worked fine:

```
protected void setBatteryAlarmSummary(String newValue){
    Preference batteryAlarm = (Preference) findPreference( getString(R.string.battery_low_alarm) );
    StringBuilder summary = new StringBuilder();
    summary.append(getString(R.string.battery_alarm_summary_label));
    summary.append(" ");
    summary.append(newValue);
    summary.append("%");
    batteryAlarm.setSummary(summary);
}
```

This sets the pref summary to "Low Battery Alarm at 10%".  Now, with ICS, it crashes.  Not when it does the setSummary, and not when the page displays, but when you scroll the preferences even a little bit, obviously triggering a render (this item is about 8 or so items down, so it's "below the fold" on the list).  Fixing ICS is easy, just escape the percent sign:

```
summary.append("%%");
```

However, that code on gingerbread displays "Low Battery Alarm at 10%%"

I can write it to change based on version, but that's just silly.  Did they really break backward compatibility on their preferences rendering, or is this just a Samsung thing (which, unfortunately, is the only test platform I have for ICS right now)?

Comment: When you ran it on an ICS emulator, what happened?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution for this... http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14355

Comment: No, I just left it with version specific code.  It worked on all the versions I had to test with.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Unicode equivalent of the percent sign, like:

`summary.append("\u0025");`

this should work.

Comment: The Java compiler itself will interpret this Unicode sequence. It is identical to actually writing % in the source file.

Comment: Yes, but then you don't have to escape it if you just write it as "%". That's the difference. I have used the Unicode value in my projects without any issue.

Comment: There is not a difference between `summary.append("%");` and `summary.append("\u0025");` though. `javac` interprets that literal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115522/a-unicode-newline-character-u000d-in-java  I don't doubt it works for you, but it does not work in the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you handle this in `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="battery_low_alarm_summary" formatted="false">Low Battery Alarm at 10%</string>
```

`formatted="false"` will make it work in all versions of Android.

But you really want a placeholder once you localize this string. I think you will have to write:

```
<string name="battery_low_alarm_summary">Low Battery Alarm at %d%%</string>
```

I have not tested this, but, I would strongly hope that buildling using any modern version of the SDK will do the right thing here, even when the result is run on old versions of Android.