# Commented code gives compilation error in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Hi I was creating simple program and got unseen compilation error in commented code.My code is as below :

```
public class Static_Method_Call
{               
    public static Character character=getMe();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Inside main() 1 : "+character); 
        //Static_Method_Call.character=new Character('\u000d'); 
        //System.out.println("Inside main() 2 : "+character);
    }

    static
    {
        System.out.println("Inside static block : "+character);
        Static_Method_Call.character=new Character('\u003d');       
    }

    public static Character getMe()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside getMe() : "+character);
        return new Character('\u002d');
    }
}
```

Error is as below :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Invalid character constant
```

What does this error mean in Java ?

Comment: You are giving the character the value of a method.  Which is not possible but there are soms more errors in your program .

Comment: @user1758777 No, OP is assigning the variable `character` to the return value of the static method `getMe()` which is perfectly valid.

Comment: look out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115522/a-unicode-newline-character-u000d-in-java

Comment: My bad. Read the code wrong ignore my comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\u000d` is a Unicode character that stands for the `CR` special character. Even *before* the compiler transforms the source code, this character is pre-processed and causes the source code to be invalid. So I guess at pre-processing, the commented line would look something like:

```
//Static_Method_Call.character=new Character('
 ');
```

Hence the compiler error. You can use `\r` to add a carriage return.

Comment: Basically this, but it shouldn't be a problem in the comments; I guess its a minor problem with the Java parser.

Comment: When this removes the compilation issue, but doesn't answer the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

\u000d is a newline character, so next line is starting with ' which is unclosed that is what it is complaining. this is explained here [A unicode newline character(\u000d) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115522/a-unicode-newline-character-u000d-in-java)

Comment: `\u000d` is a carriage return but anyway it doesn't make a difference here. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes.